# Vuex issue transforming data into observer

Tags: vue.js, vuex, flux

I am using Vuex to manage the state of my application. When I am dispatching an action that calls some data from a server API, and if then this action commits a mutation, somehow my data gets transformed to observer objects instead of the actual data. Is this an expected behaviour or a bug within vuex?

**Action:**

```
async getDataFromApi(context, payload) {
try {
    let data = callApi(foo);
    context.commit("SET_REPORTING_DATA", { data, id: payload })
    return data;
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.code);
  console.log(e.message);
  return false;
}}
```

**Mutation**

```
SET_STATE(state, data) {
state.list = { ...state.list, [data.id]: data.data }
}
```

The weird part about this is that when I log the data that I get from the API, I get an observer object although I am returning the original data from the api.

Comment: That's expected, the observer wrapper is what enables reactivity.  Vuex transforms your data object if and only if you add it to state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an issue but instead a caveat between the browser and Vue's reactivity system. To learn more about Vue's reactivity check their docs on [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html), there they explain how it works and even mention this caveat:

> One caveat is that browser consoles format getter/setters differently when converted data objects are logged...

And they recommend to use [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) for a friendlier introspection interface.

However there is a way to see logged variables with their data without having to use vue-devtools, the way is to log them using `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)))`, as shown below, to verify it correctly use the browser console, as StackOverflow's console already shows without the observer.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    obj: {
      a: 123
    }
  }),
  created() {
    console.log('Observer');
    console.log(this.obj);
    console.log('Data');
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.obj)));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```